# pointwise ergodic theorem and mean sojourn time

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $F_i$ be a sequence of finite subsets of $G$. Suppose $G$ acts on a probability measure space $(X,\mu)$ in a measure preserving way, and suppose that this action is ergodic.

Let us say that $F_i$ *satisfies pointwise ergodic theorem* iff for almost all $x\in X$, and all $f\in L^1(X)$ we have that the limit of
$$
\frac{1}{|F_i|} \sum_{g\in F_i} f(g.x)
$$
is equal to $\int_X f\, d\mu$.

Let us say that $F_i$ *satisfies mean sojourn time time* iff for every measurable $U\subset X$ and almost every $x\in X$ we have that the limit of
$$
\frac{1}{|F_i|} |\{g\in F_i\colon\, g.x \in U\}|
$$
is equal to $\mu(U)$.

It is easy to see that if $F_i$ satisfies pointwise ergodic theorem then it also satisfies mean sojourn time theorem. Is it also the other way around? A reference would be most appreciated (I imagine that the answer in the general case is the same as in the case when $G$ is the infinite cyclic group, so a reference for the latter case would also be fine)

Comment: isn't there a problem with your definitions when the $F_i$ are infinite ?

Comment: Link to the question [on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121174/)

Answer (score 1):

It is now answered at [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121174/).